# NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::ColumnDefinition with gem activerecord-postgis-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, postgis, rgeo

I want add to an existing data base the postgis extension with rails as an environment.
I have identified the [rgeo gem](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) associated with the [activerecord-postgis-adapter gem](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter)

I did the classic `bundle install`

I have followed carefully the indications by adding to my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter:            postgis
  schema_search_path: public
```

But when i launch :
`rake db:gis:setup`

i get this error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::ColumnDefinition
[...]
ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/spatial_table_definition.rb:46:in `<module:PostGIS>'
```

I have tried to install manually the postgis extension directly to my postgresql data base without success.

I have found this [solution](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/pull/246) where the author of the gem tells us it is fixed in the latest commit but did not help so much.

My versions :

- ruby 2.6.3
- active-record 6.0.0
- postgresql 11.5

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NameError: uninitialized constant >ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::ColumnDefinition
> [...]
> ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/spatial_table_definition.rb:46:in `<module:PostGIS>'
> ```

It looks like your version of `activerecord-postgis-adapter` is 3.1.2, but the current version is 6.0.1. Could you try updating to the latest version and see if that works.